# Sound glitches when I pull out my sword

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the following problem: Whenever I pull out my sword, my follower seems to be stuck in its own pulling animation which causes a horrible sound and movement issue. I tried the recommended sound bug fixes etc. but nothing seem to work. This also happens on new or older characters. I tried to reinstall it (as well as with and without my mods). [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tvrtkLNDTk&feature=youtu.be) a recording of my problem.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please post your load order.   This is usually caused by a mod which doesn't use an ESP, but affects your poses and animations.  If you have FNIS, run its configuration tool.

Comment: Uhm. I have none, I think. I used the steam workshop. I'm not really deep into modding so this seemed to be the easiest way.

Comment: Nothing available to the workshop should cause this, since the mods there are usually pretty rudimentary compared to what you can do with SKSE and Nexus mods.  I just go to see the video so I think I have some tips, answer to come.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those "it just happens sometimes" Bethesda bugs I've seen pop up.  Usually, it's because either a weapon mod tried to bring its own idle animation with it, or an animation mod in general has failed to load properly.  It can also happen just because, and is actually less likely when using modded-in animation sets. If you're on PC, I strongly recommend Fores New Idles (FNIS) from the Nexus; it fixes a LOT and vastly improves animation quality.

If you've got no mods installed that affect animations and this happens, most of your options involve the PC console.   You can try to use the `resurrect` console command to forcibly reset the follower.   `kill` can also be used to force essential characters into the "bleeding out" kneeling stance, which can fix broken animations.

Gameplay fix options include simply dismissing the follower and seeing if resuming their daily lives fixes them, as well as "sprinting" into them at full speed and making them do the "knock back" animation.  Both of these fix a LOT of animation bugs that are inherent to Bethesda games using the Gamebryo engine.  The first word of Unrelenting Force, "Fus", can fix them as well.   You can try a full "Fus-roh-dah" and blast them across the room if that doesn't work, but they may not want to be your friend no more if you do that. 
The problem can also exist with the weapon.  I had a follower once who was someone's first project that did something similar to this every time they tried to draw a hip-scabbard weapon like a sword or knife.   They had no issue with greatswords and bows, so I robbed them blind and gave them equipment that didn't glitch them.    In another case, the source of the issue was the actual mod that brought the weapon in; it had a custom animation which seemed to be broken.